# The vote against humanity

Tags: diablo-series

Zoltan Kulle talks about it before you revive him...

The angels already had a vote whether to destroy humanity or not.

We know that Imperius was for and Tyriael was against.

What were the other votes, and why did they vote that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your question is answered in dialog options for Tyrael somewhere in Act 4.
The votes are as follows:

Tyrael and Auriel voted for humanity, Imperius against and Malthael abstained. Tyrael does not give any detail on why the votes where cast that way, just who voted and the nature of their vote.

Here is a link to an achievement guide for the conversation achievement for Tyrael: http://soe.hubpages.com/hub/Tyrael-Lore-and-Character-Dialogue-Guide-Diablo-3

The relevant conversation option is "Malthael". The option became available at the entrance to the room where you fight Diablo in the pinnacle of heaven, during the last Questline of Act 4.

Itherael also voted for humanity. You can find this out by talking to him in Act 4.
http://www.d3lexicon.com/conversation/itherael-nephalem-gossip#witch-doctor-male